# Polycarbonate exterior wall on steel frame building

Tags: exterior, steel, house

I'm doing some research on constructing a steel framed house. I initially thought aluminum sheets would be cheaper and lighter than steel. But polycarbonate sheets would be even lighter, cheaper and it doesn't corrode.

I therefore thought I could glue that to the steel frame of the building and the steel tubes. Apply some white epoxy type of paint to it and the steel frame, and drill or glue composite wood or normal wood to the polycarbonate sheet.

As for the interior, I was thinking of using 3 inches of closed cell foam spray.

Am I better off doing something else? What are the potential downsides of this implementation?

Am I better off using real wood than composite on the exterior as I can therefore paint it with exterior paint to reduce the chances of any water seeping through the boards? Is drilling into, and creating holes, right into the spray foam not a good idea? Could that let moisture in and create condensation between the closed cell spray foam and polycarbonate sheet?

Comment: I'd be a more than a little concerned about fire safety. Steel and aluminum are great. Wood is, surprisingly (since we think of burning wood to make a fire in a campground or fireplace) actually pretty good. A *lot* of foam insulation is not very safe (either catches fire easily or creates incredibly toxic smoke). I have no idea as far as polycarbonate sheets in terms of strength, fire safety, etc. Also relevant: How big is this - i.e., McMansion or tiny home or something in between? Is the light weight for ease of construction or because you want to be able to move the house in the future?

Comment: Homes have lateral systems for resisting wind and earthquake. The sheathing installed on the outside of wood framing typically fills this role. You've got a lateral system in mind, right? I've never seriously studied it, but the IRC has a steel wall framing section, R603.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'm planning to use an environment friendly and fire resistant foam insulation. The house would be 40 x 30 ft. The idea is to build a prototype for a potential prefab construction in the future.

Comment: @popham The house would be built in a non-earthquake area. As for wind, I'm thinking the metal studs would resist any lateral pressure exerted on them. As well as the outer composite or wood framing.

Comment: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR603.9.2 will put you in the thick of things. The point I was trying to make is that the aluminum may provide sufficient wall bracing, whereas the poly may not (or vice versa). Putzing around a bit, the IRC doesn't seem interested in cladding that doubles as wall bracing, but maybe there's some fine print in there.

Comment: @popham Not planning to build anything in the US. But you make a good point there with local regulations. That's definitely something to keep in mind

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take the [tour] and a quick spin through [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). "Is this an insane idea or does it make sense?" is _very_ much opinion based and off-topic, as is "Am I better off...", leaving only "drilling/holes into foam not a good idea" which is, as stated, also somewhat opinion-based, but also very vague. What would these holes be for?

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you :) What the holes are for I address in a paragraph above: _and drill or glue composite wood or normal wood to the polycarbonate sheet_. It is a bit vague though, I am going to add some more detail.

Comment: Attaching _anything_ to spray foam is an idea fraught with issues. Spray foam has absolutely _ZERO_ structural integrity and will not hold a screw, and any glue that might stick to it probably has chemicals in it that would simply dissolve the foam leaving a sticky mess (at best) or nothing solid for the glued thing to stick to.

Comment: @FreeMan The foam won't no. But the polycarbonate sheet would. Enough to keep the wood or composite affixed to the wall. But in doing so would create a hole that could allow for moisture to penetrate. That was my concern. Glue would not have that problem but that would make it harder to remove to make inspections or do replacements of the outer cladding.

Comment: You explicitly ask, "Is drilling into, and creating holes, right into the spray foam not a good idea?" so my comment addressed that. If that's not what you meant, you might want to clarify...

Comment: It's not about local regulations. The IRC (or some analogue) captures a set of sufficient conditions that provide a sound home. And it's the walls running parallel to the wind that ultimately carry wind load down to the foundation, right? Alternatively, some kind of diagonal bracing gets used, but I don't think that's in the IRC for steel framing.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, and good point. I've updated my question already based on your feedback.

Comment: @popham Not sure what you mean. Whatever material you use, be it steel, aluminum, or plastic. It needs to support the lateral load. Which I am planning to account for.

Comment: If you anticipate, say, a maximum wind of 90 mph, then a rough estimate of the wall pressure is (0.00256)(90)^2 = 21 psf. It's center of force is halfway up the wall, so assuming a 40 ft by 8 ft wall, that's equivalent to (21psf)(40ft)(8ft) = 6600# applied with 4 ft of leverage midway up the wall. It will knock the whole wall down without bracing. You need a system to carry the load down to the foundation and a system to gather that 6600# and transport it to the first system. Wall bracing and roof diaphragms do this.

Comment: @popham The metal studs run from the top of the steel frame to the bottom. The steel frame is attached to the foundation. The only concern is how many metal studs are needed per foot. Something I will have a structural engineer decide.

Comment: Or maybe studs is not the correct word. They'd really be like 1.5 inch steel tubes

Comment: I guess you can retrofit diagonal steel ties or something in for a lateral system and roof diaphragm after you've installed cladding, so goofing this up isn't a horribly expensive mistake. Just be sure to talk to your engineer before you finish any interior surfaces of exterior walls.

Answer (score 2):

Polycarbonate (usually but not always corrugated twinwall or triplewall) on steel framing is common in the greenhouse industry.

What you appear not to have considered is different rates of thermal expansion between polycarbonate and steel. Greenhouse systems typically employ sliding channels for joints so that the materials can shrink and grow relative to each other without the structure as a whole distorting. Gluing the panels to the steel frame would likely encounter problems due to the different rates of thermal expansion.

You might want to investigate how greenhouse builders have solved the problem and learn from their solutions. *You might even find it cost-efficient to purchase a polycarbonate-glazed greenhouse in the size you require.*

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps predrilling it to allow for thermal expansion and fitting it with rubber screws and silicone at the edges to prevent water penetration is a much better option

Comment: Or, @dan-klasson, "You might want to investigate how greenhouse builders have solved the problem and learn from their solutions." Since the answer indicates sliding channels for the joints and not drilling and fitting with rubber screws (whatever those may be) and silicone, that doesn't seem to be learning, but coming up with a new solution. However, it's your project, so have at!

Comment: Again, good point. But I am not building a greenhouse. The plastic I will be using won't be transparent nor directly facing the sun. But I will definitely look into it. Thanks.

Comment: They may not be transparent/translucent, but I'm betting the construction techniques are 99.999% the same.

Comment: @FreeMan The wall won't be directly in the sun due to the roof. And a lot of heat will be absorbed by the composite or wood. Therefore I think the thermal expansion won't be as much of an issue. But definitely something to consider.

Comment: I suggest, @dan-klasson, that you build it your way and see what happens. That's the only way you'll know for sure...

Comment: Maybe, @dan-klasson, it seems toxic because you haven't asked an objective question that can be answered in the SE format, despite having been politely asked several times to do so... Maybe _we_ aren't the toxic ones. :shrug: